# Use ctypes with typedef

Tags: python, c, typedef, ctypes

I would like to call a C function

```
void initialize(My_Session* session, My_Status* status);
```

from Python using ctypes. The datatypes are defined by

```
typedef uint32_t My_Session;
typedef int32_t My_Status;
```

Now I would like to know how I can pass the arguments using ctypes. Do I use `c_uint32` and `c_int32`, or do I have to define a class like it is done for structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from eryksun got me on track.

In the python file I had to define:

```
from ctypes import *

_libtest = CDLL('libTest')

_libtest.initialize.argtypes = [POINTER(c_uint32), POINTER(c_int32)]
_libtest.initialize.restype  =  None

def initialize(session,status):
    return _libtest.initialize(byref(session),byref(status))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = c_uint32();
    status = c_int32();

    initialize(session, status)

    print status
```

The name of the C library has to be libTest.dll.

---

Alternatively, define `initialize` to create the ctypes integers. Then return `session` and `status` as Python integers:

```
def initialize():
    session = c_uint32()
    status = c_int32()
    _libtest.initialize(byref(session), byref(status))
    return session.value, status.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session, status = initialize()
    print 'session:', session
    print 'status:', status
```

Comment: Thanks eryksun! I changed stuff according to your suggestions. I have followed the example in http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-6A-Fortran-and-C.ipynb Thats why I came to use the numpy.ctypeslib.

Will the CDLL function also recognize libTest.so on unix systems?

Comment: It is a private library that I use here. I just wanted to know whether I can use the same function when I do similar stuff in Linux. If I got it right I need to call `CDLL('libtest.so')` in this case.